# How to get information about a particular Dask task

Tags: python, distributed, dask

I'm running into a problem whereby my distributed cluster appears to "hang" - e.g. tasks stop processing and hence a backlog of unprocessed tasks builds up so I'm looking for some way to help debug what's going on.

On the `Client` there's the `processing` method which will tell me what tasks are currently running on each worker but AFAICS that's the only info about the tasks available on the `Client` object?

What I'd like to to is to be able to query not just processing tasks, but all tasks including processed, processing and errored and for each task to be able to get some statistics such as `submitted_time` and `completion_time` which would allow me to find out what tasks are blocking the cluster.

This would be similar to the extended metadata on the [`ipyparallel.AsyncResult`](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html#extended-interface)

A nice to have would be to to be able to get the `args/kwargs` for any give task too. This would be especially helpful in debugging failed tasks.

Is any of this functionality available currently or is there any way to get the info I'm after?

Any other suggestions on how to debug the problem would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of May 2017 no explicit "give me all of the information about a task" operation exists.  However, you can use the client to investigate task state directly.  This will require you to dive a bit into the information that the scheduler and worker track.  See the following doc pages:

- http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scheduling-state.html
- http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worker.html#api-documentation

To query this state I would use the [Client.run_on_scheduler](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.run_on_scheduler) and [Client.run](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.client.Client.run) methods.  These take a function to run on the scheduler or workers respsectively.  If this function includes a `dask_scheduler` or `dask_worker` argument then the function will be given the scheduler or worker object itself.

```
def f(dask_scheduler):
    return dask_scheduler.task_state

client.run_on_scheduler(f)
```

You now have access to check any state that the scheduler or workers know about and to run any internal diagnostic checks.  What you choose to investigate though depends entirely on your use case.

```
def f(keys, dask_scheduler=None):
    return dask_scheduler.transition_story(*keys)

client.run_on_scheduler(f, [key1, key2, key3])
```

Comment: Looks like that should be:
<code>
    def f(keys, dask_scheduler):
        return dask_scheduler.transition_story(*keys)
</code>

Comment: Thanks @DaveHirschfeld.   Fixed

Comment: It looks like you now have to call `dask_scheduler.tasks` instead; see https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/1904